# Arm template for Azure Function with slots and restricted storage account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, vnet

I have an azure premium function which I want deployed to a storage account which is protected via vnet. I have followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-networking-how-to#restrict-your-storage-account-to-a-virtual-network and it works fine.

I now want to add slots to the template to allow me to hot swap the deployment in live

If I deploy the arm template with slots added (but no configuration specified for the slot at all, so it should get all the app settings from production) I can see it's changed `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` in the staging slot by adding `2452965d` as shown below:

[image]

I can't actually deploy to the slot now without manually creating the share `***-dev-2452965d` in the storage account (previously to deploy without a slot I needed to create the share `***-dev` so this isn't a surprise.

It will then correctly deploy the app to the slot.

Where things fail now is trying to swap the deployment. Clicking swap in the portal gives this error:-

> Failed to complete swap between slot 'staging' and slot 'production'. Error: {"_body":"{"Code":"InternalServerError","Message":"There was an unexpected error swapping slots 'staging' and 'production' for site '***-dev(staging)'. Please try to cancel your swap operation

I'm guessing this error is because the storage account is behind a vnet and I still need to manually create the shares or manipulate them in someway but can't. I'm at a loss if there is a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Microsoft this:

> So can you confirm that premium functions using storage secured behind a vnet do not support slots. I just can’t find this documented anywhere.

And they replied with:

> Hello Ross,
> I tried to get supportive documentation myself but couldn't get one yet.
> However, it does not support swapping if the storage account is behind VNet.
> My Best Regards,

So it's just not supported, nor documented anywhere sadly.